# Mathematical induction proof of $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} F_{2i} = F_{2n + 1} - 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Use Mathematical Induction to show that

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n F_{2i}=F_{2n+1}-1$$

for all integer $n\geq1$.

My answer:

Base case:

for n = 1

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} F_{2i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{1} F_{2i} = F_{2 \cdot 1} = F_{3-1} = F_{2n+1} -1$$

Inductive Step:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} F_{2i} = F_2 + F_4 + \ldots + F_{2(n + 1)} = F_{2(n + 1) + 1} - 1$$

Comment: Is $F_j$ the $j$-th Fibonacci number?

Comment: @Bens. Yeah it is :D

Comment: Hint: Use $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}F_{2i}=F_{2(n+1)}+\sum_{i=1}^nF_{2i}$.

Comment: @bens. how do i apply that to the question? i tried working it out, but didnt really get anywhere. Im sorta new to mathematical induction, sigma and fionacci? thanks for the hint though! xo

Comment: Have you done the base case?  What is your induction assumption?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig ive done both steps, just not sure if theyre correct. Is there anyway i can post what ive done?

Comment: Yes.  If you click on edit (at the bottom of your post), you can include that information after what you have written.  Including the work you have done on the problem will increase your chances of getting a response that addresses the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig how do i do the sigma signs? lol :)

Comment: You type \sum_{i = 1}^{n} F_{2i} = F_{2n + 1} - 1 between dollar signs to obtain $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} F_{2i} = F_{2n + 1} - 1$.  You can read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In your base case, you need to establish that $F_2 = F_3 - 1$.  What is $F_2$? $F_3$?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig The fibinacci numbers? ahah

Comment: @N. F. Taussig I uploaded what i got, it's sort of hard to draw in maths though :( thanks for your help so far though :) x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement $$\sum_{k = 1}^n F_{2k} = F_{2n + 1} - 1$$

To prove the statement holds for each positive integer $n$ by mathematical induction, we must show that $P(1)$ holds and that $P(m + 1)$ holds whenever $P(m)$ holds since then we will have established the chain of implications $$P(1) \Rightarrow P(2) \Rightarrow P(3) \Rightarrow \cdots$$

In this case, we will need to use the properties of the Fibonacci sequence, which is defined recursively by 
\begin{align*}
F_1 & = 1\\
F_2 & = 1\\
F_{n} & = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}, \text{if $n \geq 3$}
\end{align*}
In particular, we have 
$$F_3 = F_{3 - 1} + F_{3 - 2} = F_2 + F_1 = 1 + 1 = 2$$

**Base case:**  We show that $P(1)$ holds.

If $n = 1$, then 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{1} F_{2k} = F_{2 \cdot 1} = F_2 = 1 = 2 - 1 = F_{3} - 1 = F_{2 \cdot 1 + 1} - 1$$
so $P(1)$ holds.

**Inductive hypothesis:**

Since $P(1)$ holds, we may assume $P(m)$ holds for some positive integer $m$.  Thus, 
$$\color{green}{\sum_{k = 1}^{m} F_{2k} = F_{2m + 1} - 1}$$

**Inductive step:**  We must show that $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m + 1)$ for each positive integer $m$.

Let $n = m + 1$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{m + 1} F_{2k} & = \color{green}{\sum_{k = 1}^{m} F_{2k}} + F_{2(m + 1)}\\
                            & = \color{green}{F_{2m + 1} - 1} + F_{2m + 2}\\
                            & = F_{2m + 3} - 1\\
                            & = F_{2(m + 1) + 1} - 1 
\end{align*}
Hence, $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m + 1)$ for each positive integer $m$.

Since $P(1)$ holds and $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m + 1)$ for each positive integer $m$, $P(n)$ holds for each positive integer $n$.$\blacksquare$

Note we have used the fact that $F_{n} = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}$ when $n = 2m + 3$ to establish that $F_{2m + 3} = F_{2m + 2} + F_{2m + 1}$.